# qemu-system-ppc64 no peer warning while trying boot and bring up ethernet interface

Tags: qemu, kvm, powerpc

I am trying to emulate PPC64e5500 CPU using QEMU but while trying to bring up the ethernet interface in the machine I am getting **no peer warning**.

```
$sudo ~/QorIQ-SDK-V1.6-20140619-yocto/build_t1040rdb_release/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/qemu-system-ppc64 -cpu e5500 -nographic -m 256 -M ppce500 -kernel uImage -initrd fsl-image-minimal-t1040rdb-20141223093206.rootfs.ext2.gz -append "root=/dev/ram rw console=ttyS0,115200 ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0 mem=128M" -serial tcp::4444,server,telnet -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000
```

The output of the above command is given below

```
QEMU 1.7.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) QEMU waiting for connection on: telnet:0.0.0.0:4444,server
Warning: nic e1000.0 has no peer
```

Now even while the machine is booting it report

```
NET: Registered protocol family 10
sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
Key type dns_resolver registered
fsl_dpa_macless: FSL DPAA MACless Ethernet driver ()
fsl_dpa_generic: FSL DPAA Generic Ethernet driver ()
drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
**8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0**
e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, hwaddr=52:54:00:12:34:57, ipaddr=192.168.7.2, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.7.1
     host=192.168.7.2, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
     bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=255.255.255.255, rootpath=
```

As it report **8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0** so I am not able even to ping the gateway as same can be verified as below

```
root@model:~# ping 192.168.7.1
PING 192.168.7.1 (192.168.7.1): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.7.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

The route -n shows below output

```
root@model:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

So any thoughts why the eth0 is getting added to VLan as even I have not created one and how to fix  it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  know about CPU e5500, but for ppc64, I have been using device spapr-vlan very successfully.

This is the qemu line I use:

```
qemu-system-ppc64 -enable-kvm -nographic -nodefaults -monitor stdio -serial pty -M pseries -smp 1,cores=1,threads=8 -m 4G -device spapr-vlan,netdev=net0,mac=4c:45:42:45:02:02 -netdev bridge,id=net0,br=br0
```